# How to align an indented line in a span that wraps into multiple lines?

Tags: css, html

Does anyone have an idea how to align the second line?

[image]

```css
span.info {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="info"></span>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
display:block;
```

then you've got a block element and the margin is added to all lines.

While it's true that a span is semantically not a block element, there are cases where you don't have control of the pages DOM. This answer is inteded for those.

Comment: Making a span display:block is horrible practice; a block-level span is called a div.

Comment: @Adrian is that still the case if the span sits inside a paragraph (it's content being semantically part of the paragraph), but visually it needs to sit on it's own line? A <div> would break this layout.

Comment: @som Why would content that's semantically part of a paragraph need to be on its own line, breaking the paragraph? That doesn't sound like a paragraph to me.

Comment: @Adrian I agree it wouldn't be something that happens often, but even in print paragraphs sometimes have funky formatting (especially in kid's books). The text is still meant to be read as part of the containing paragraph. We're talking about semantic markup, not appearance.

Comment: @Adrian in my case I need to use that because I do NOT have control of the mechanism that produces the raw html, but I do have control over the css used. This approach allowed me to fix the layout.

Comment: While it's true that a span is semantically not a block element, there are cases where you don't have control of the pages DOM. This answer is inteded for those.

Comment: A span is not “semantically not a block element”. It can be styled however you want it. It doesn’t mean anything on its own. See [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element).

Answer (score 25):

[`<span>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) are inline elements, as such layout properties such as `width` or `margin` don't work. You can fix that by either changing the `<span>` to a block element (such as `<div>`), or by using padding instead.

Note that making a `span` element a block element by adding `display: block;` is redundant, as a `span` is by definition a otherwise style-less inline element whereas `div` is an otherwise style-less block element. So the correct solution is to use a `div` instead of a block-`span`.

Comment: I believe changing the `span` to `p` is more "semantically" correct than using `div`.

Comment: From the way I understand the displayed text, it is more meant as an information bit that is displayed below some input form. While using `p` is in general the better way, I don't think making that info text a paragraph, and applying all the paragraph styles to it, fits.

Comment: Padding does not seem to work... seems to affect only the first row.

Comment: For the love of all that is good and right in the world, why isn't this the accepted answer.... Sheesh...

Answer (score 11):

`span` is a inline element which means if you use `<br/>` it'll b considered as one line anyway.

Change `span` to a block element or add `display:block` to your class.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/tZtpr/1/

Answer (score 10):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
Line no one
Line no two
And many more line.
This is Manik
End of Line
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe your solution and explain why it works

Comment: @Ivan not actually spam. "A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited message." https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor  He did copy part of this into another answer, but that doesn't make it spam. You could leave a comment on the newer copied material linking to the source, criticize the approach, and downvote. You can even raise a custom flag. But don't flag this for spam.

Comment: @AaronHall, alright fair enough, I have changed flag

Comment: Works for me, dunno why.. but i can live with that.

Answer (score 5):

try to add `display: block;` (or replace the `<span>` by a `<div>`) (note that this could cause other problems becuase a `<span>` is inline by default - but you havn't posted the rest of your html)

Answer (score 5):

Also you can try to use

```
display:inline-block;
```

if you would like the span element to align horizontally.

Incase you would like to align span elements vertically, just use

```
 display:block;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want multiple lines of text indented on the left. Try the following:

CSS:

```
div.info {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

span.info {
    color: #b1b1b1;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="info"><span class="info">blah blah <br/> blah blah</span></div>
```