# Span tag in h1 tag causing line break

Tags: inline

Can anyone tell me what is happening on [this site](http://marazuldelsur.com/bwh/)

I have a span tag within an h1 tag to change the color of the & in the title. Span is an inline element, I don't get it. I have tried changing the h1 to a div tag or a p tag, the span resolutely makes a line break. What am I missing? I'm totally stumped here....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Span line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677976/span-line-break)

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the markup in question and added more detail like the browser you're using.  Also, try to duplicate the issue on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as that will allow people to more easily come up with a solution (if one is necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule to your stylesheet:

```
.site-header h1 span:after {
    display: inline;
}
```

span is an inline element, but its default behavior is being overridden by the following CSS rule that begins on line 54 of your stylesheet:

```
.author-box:after,
.clearfix:after,
.entry:after,
.entry-content:after,
.footer-widgets:after,
.nav-primary:after,
.nav-secondary:after,
.pagination:after,
.site-container:after,
.site-footer:after,
.site-header:after,

:after, // This line gets overridden with the more specific selector provided above
.wrap:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for that! I have just realized that all the :after elements are causing havoc further down the line. I think I'll remove them all and restyle individually as needed.